# spring boot resource as links

Tags: spring, rest, api, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot, I have used it to implement a rest API. I have a self referencing table where each item has a parent -tree structure- . I have used ManyToOne to implement this and i get a json object which holds the parent.  If i get all the items the speed is very slow since there are a huge network latency and processing because my tree can hold up to 10000 item.

How can I represent this using links, i.e the the json object contains a link to parent and array of links to children. I have read that DTO can be used to implement this but I did not find a full details.

part of my code

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "Item", schema = "dbo")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class Item {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column()
        private Integer ItemID;
        @Column()
        private String Project;
        @Column()
        private String Name;
        @Column()
        private Integer Version; 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "ParentItemID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private Item parentItem;

My controller is strait forward 

@Autowired
    ItemService ItemService;
    @RequestMapping ("/items")
    public Iterable<Item> items(@RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "0") Integer page,
            @RequestParam(value = "size", defaultValue = "20") Integer size, Authentication auth) {
        return ItemService.findPaginated(page, size);
    }
```

I would be glad if i get more explanation on how to  use DTOs , or another design to get links instead of full objects.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing you can do is, return parent and children ids instead of Item objects.

```
@Entity
    @Table(name = "Item", schema = "dbo")
    public class Item {
       .
       .  
       private Integer ItemID;
       private Integer parentItem;
       .
       .
```

Have another endpoint in your controller like `/items/{itemId}`

```
@GetMapping("/items/{itemId}")
public Item item(@PathVariable itemId, Authentication auth) {
  return ItemService.findById(itemId);
```

Let your consumer grab the parent/children Ids and make separate REST calls

---

Alternatively, you can use Spring-HATEOAS

> The Spring HATEOAS project is a library of APIs that we can use to
>   easily create REST representations that follow the principle of
>   HATEOAS (Hypertext as the Engine of Application State).
>
> Generally speaking, the principle implies that the API should guide
>   the client through the through the application by returning relevant
>   information about the next potential steps, along with each response.

More Information [Here](https://spring.io/projects/spring-hateoas)